# Getting Paper_trail + Rails_admin + Devise with Multiple 'user' models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I am developing an app in Rails 3, currently I use Devise as the login and Rails_admin as the admin panel with Paper_trail tracking all changes made by 'user' model... Problem is I have two user models, User and Admin. So a line of code in rails_admin.rb (initiliazer) to setup Paper_trail to track history:

```
  config.audit_with :paper_trail, User
```

**Is there any way to have paper_trail monitor changes made by both User and Admin, or can it only follow one model?** I notice that even when it is set like this, and I make a change from within Rails_admin as an admin, the change says it was made by the User with the same ID as the admin that made the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to install CanCan, remove my Admin Model, and take advantage of using Multiple Roles within a single model for the current situation.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, maybe there has been some change to this... Is there really no alternative to support multiple devise models? I have already built my application around that concept and would be a pain to revert it now....  And if I was to, how would I go about it?