# Rails papertrail with multiple devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paper-trail-gem

Is there a solution to using papertrail on an application that has multiple devise models?

I know there was a [post in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352491/getting-paper-trail-rails-admin-devise-with-multiple-user-models) with an answer inclined to deny the existence of a solution, but maybe there have been changes.

I have 2 devise models, admin and user, and I am stuck where papertrail says I should add this:

```
config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version'
```

EDIT: I am using rails_admin, as a matter of fact, the [rails_admin+papertrail integration page](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Papertrail) that indicates I should use the line above on rails_admin.rb.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, I can set the whodunnit user myself on the ApplicationController.

I learned it after seeing the warning message on the console that points to [this page](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/doc/warning_about_not_setting_whodunnit.md).